# Vuejs binding to img src only works on component rerender

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I got a component that let's the user upload a profile picture with a preview before sending it off to cloudinary.

```
<template>
<div>
    <div
        class="image-input"
        :style="{ 'background-image': `url(${person.personData.imagePreview})` } "
        @click="chooseImage"
    >
        <span
            v-if="!person.personData.imagePreview"
            class="placeholder"
        >
            <i class="el-icon-plus avatar-uploader-icon"></i>
        </span>
        <input
            type="file"
            ref="fileInput"
            @change="previewImage"
        >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The methods to handle the preview:

```
chooseImage() {
    this.$refs.fileInput.click()
},
previewImage(event) {
            // Reference to the DOM input element
            const input = event.target;
            const files = input.files

            console.log("File: ", input.files)

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                this.person.personData.image = files[0];

                const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.person.personData.imagePreview = e.target.result;
                }
                // Start the reader job - read file as a data url (base64 format)
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        },
```

This works fine, except for when the user fetches a previous project from the DB. `this.person.personData.imagePreview` get's set to something like `https://res.cloudinary.com/resumecloud/image/upload/.....id.jpg` Then when the user wants to change his profile picture, he is able to select a new one from his local file system, and `this.person.personData.imagePreview` is read again as a data url with base64 format. But the preview doesn't work. Only when I change routes back and forth, the correct image selected by the user is displayed.

Comment: Could be a reactivity issue due to your nested objects. Take a look at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html (specifically `Vue.set...`) and see if that helps, if not we need more to go on to help you, maybe you can showcase the problem on a codesandbox/jsfiddle.

Comment: sounds like your component is loading before the picture is retrieved, you can put a `v-if` on it or force a rerender once it arrives.

Comment: Wow, I literally solved this stupid bug 1 sec ago. Turns out I'm an idiot. When displaying the preview, I used `this.person.personData.imagePreview` . When a user fetches a project from the DB, I just did `this.person.personData = response.data`. That works fine, apart from the fact that I had a different name for `imagePreview` on my backend. So I manually set it on the same `load` method when fetching from the DB like:  `this.person.personData.imagePreview = this.loadedPersonData.file`. For some reason, that screwed with the reactivity of Vue. Thanks for the comments guys, definitely helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment on my post. Turns out I'm an idiot. When displaying the preview, I used `this.person.personData.imagePreview` . When a user fetches a project from the DB, I just did `this.person.personData = response.data`. That works fine, apart from the fact that I had a different name for `imagePreview` on my backend. So I manually set it on the same load method when fetching from the DB like: `this.person.personData.imagePreview = this.loadedPersonData.file`. For some reason, that screwed with the reactivity of Vue.